# Определение активного виджета в окне

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qplaintextedit

Помогите определить активный виджет, пример работающего варианта прилагаю в начале, опираясь на который пытаюсь реализовать свой. Но только добился отрисовки без функциональных возможностей.

Задача определить номер активного виджета (это мне надо для виртуальной клавиатуры, чтобы при смене фокуса, т.е. при нажатии кнопок, мог выводить в выбранный до этого виджет).

Конкретно проблема - когда добавляю конструктор класса в класс `MyQPlainTextEdit`, перестают работать все виджеты (не поставить курсор в поле ввода), этим действием хочу добавить переменную `id` для определения активного виджета. В `id` передать `MyQPlainTextEdit(1)` например.

Пример работающего варианта:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyLineEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, id):
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self)
        self.id = id

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        print("Получен фокус полем", self.id)
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusInEvent(self, e)

    def focusOutEvent(self, e):
        print("Потерян фокус полем", self.id)
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusOutEvent(self, e)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(300, 100)

        self.line1 = MyLineEdit(1)
        self.line2 = MyLineEdit(2)
        self.line3 = MyLineEdit(3)
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.line3)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Моя попытка реализации:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt, QDateTime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyQPlainTextEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, id):
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self)
        self.id = id
    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        print("Получен фокус полем", self.id)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow; color: red;")
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusInEvent(self, e)
    def focusOutEvent(self, e):
        print("Потерян фокус полем", self.id)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusOutEvent(self, e)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):   #  object,
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(801, 208)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 150, 191, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:  rgb(73, 71, 71);\n"
"    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 51, 17))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 151, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 67, 17))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 39, 201, 21))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 40, 121, 17))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -1, 811, 31))
        self.label_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(73, 71, 71);\n"
"    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")

        self.plainTextEdit = MyQPlainTextEdit(Form)
        # self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 291, 70))
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText("")
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = MyQPlainTextEdit(Form)
        # self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 291, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = MyQPlainTextEdit(Form)
        # self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 60, 261, 70))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_3")
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = MyQPlainTextEdit(Form)
        # self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 150, 261, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.plainTextEdit_5 = MyQPlainTextEdit(Form)
        # self.plainTextEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 60, 211, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_5")

        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "СОХРАНИТЬ"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "ФИО:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Наименование ЛПУ:"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "E-mail:"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "Создайте пароль доступа:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Специализация:"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ НОВОГО ОПЕРАТОРА"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt, QDateTime


class MyQPlainTextEdit(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, id, parent):                                    # !!! +++
        super().__init__(parent)                                       # !!! +++
        
        self.id = id
        
    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        print("Получен фокус полем", self.id)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow; color: red;")
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusInEvent(self, e)
        
    def focusOutEvent(self, e):
        print("Потерян фокус полем", self.id)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; color: black;")
        QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit.focusOutEvent(self, e)


class Ui_Form(object):                                                # !!! object,
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(801, 208)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 150, 191, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color:  rgb(73, 71, 71);\n"
"    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"   \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 51, 17))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 151, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 67, 17))
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 39, 201, 21))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 40, 121, 17))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, -1, 811, 31))
        self.label_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(73, 71, 71);\n"
"    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        
# !!! +++ ----------------------------------> v  vvvv <-----------------------------------
        self.plainTextEdit = MyQPlainTextEdit(1, Form)                           # !!! +++
        # self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 291, 70))
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlainText("plainTextEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = MyQPlainTextEdit(2, Form)                           # !!! +++
        # self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 291, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_2")
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = MyQPlainTextEdit(3, Form)                           # !!! +++
        # self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 60, 261, 70))
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_3")
        self.plainTextEdit_4 = MyQPlainTextEdit(4, Form)                           # !!! +++
        # self.plainTextEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 150, 261, 51))
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_4")
        self.plainTextEdit_5 = MyQPlainTextEdit(5, Form)                           # !!! +++
        # self.plainTextEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 60, 211, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setStyleSheet("background-color:  rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setObjectName("plainTextEdit_5")
        
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0fff0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0fff0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0fff0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_4.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0fff0; border: none')
        self.plainTextEdit_5.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0fff0; border: none')
        
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "СОХРАНИТЬ"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "ФИО:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Наименование ЛПУ:"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "E-mail:"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "Создайте пароль доступа:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "Специализация:"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ НОВОГО ОПЕРАТОРА"))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):                               # !!! +++
    def __init__(self):                                                   # !!! +++
        super().__init__()                                                # !!! +++
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                                # !!! +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо большое.

Comment: @Zhukovvv пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour